# How does var "pos" (position in the array) decrement at line 17 in this code?

Tags: recursion

This code finds all the combinations of the letters A, B, C. I'm trying to 
understand how var "pos" (position in the array) behaves. After the 
recursive call of the comb method at line 18, control returns to the end of 
the block at line 18 then goes up and executes line 17. I've established 
this by inserting print statements all over the place. My questions:

Why does control return to line 17?

"pos" decrements from 2 to 1 after line 17. How does that happen?

```
1 public class MyProgram {
2 public static void main(String[] args) {
3    comb("ABC",new boolean[3],0);
4}
5//use bool array to say include/or not
6 static void comb(String x, boolean[] inc, int pos){
7   
8   if(pos==inc.length) {                   //we reached the end
9       for(int i=0;i<inc.length;i++) {
10           if(inc[i]) System.out.print(x.charAt(i));  //print each 
11     character we include
12        }
13        System.out.println(); return;   //exit
14    }
15    inc[pos] = true;    //include this character
16    comb(x,inc,pos+1);  //recurse
17    inc[pos] = false;   //do not include this character
18    comb(x,inc,pos+1);  //recurse
19} 
20 }
This code finds all the combinations of the letters A, B, C. I'm trying to 
understand how var "pos" (position in the array) behaves. After the 
recursive call of the comb method at line 18, control returns to the end of 
the block at line 18 then goes up and executes line 17. I've established 
this by inserting print statements all over the place. My questions:

Why does control return to line 17?

 "pos" decrements from 2 to 1 after line 17. How does that happen?

I'm trying to think of anything else I could add to get this code posted. 
I'm studying for a technical exam as part of an interview process. Based on 
sample questions, I believe mastery of this kind of technique would be good 
to understand. Thanks to all for any help!
```

Comment: Because you called it from line 16, so after return it continues at line 17.

Comment: I'm talking about when line 18 executes. From research using print statements, control returns to the bottom of that block that ends at line 18. The next thing that happens is it sets inc[pos] to false, but before it does that it decrments pos by 1 (from 2 to 1). Why does it go back to 17, and how does it decrement?

Comment: It doesn't "go back to 17", it _returns from comb_ to line 17. Also it doesn't decrement `pos`, this variable was _always_ 1 in this stack frame.

Comment: How does it decrement pos from 2 to 1?

Comment: It doesn't. It calls `comb` with `pos + 1`, which then is `2` in this second call. When it returns, you're back in your original call in which pos is and always was `1`.

Comment: Doesn't pos have to be 2 in order to execute the body of the if statement? length of the array is 3, so in order for the if statement to be true, pos +1 has to equal 3, no? Can the pos of the if statement and the pos in line 15 thru 18 have different values?

Comment: `pos` _will_ be 3 in some of the invocations, but once it returns, it'll be back in a stack frame where it's 2.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're thinking too much about variables changing magically (which they don't) and control-flow going up instead down (which doesn't) and don't thinl hard enough about the call-graph. Take a look at this simple example:

```
// hello() is called from main
void hello() {
    int pos = 2;
    System.out.println("In Hello, Pos is " + pos);
    world(pos + 1);
    System.out.println("In Hello, Pos is still" + pos);
}

void world(int pos) {
    System.out.println("In World, Pos is " + pos);
}
```

Can you see how control flows through the functions? `hello` has a `pos` variable with the value `2` which it prints. Then it calls `world` with `3`, which it prints and once `world` returns, `hello` has still it's original `pos` variable with the value `2`. This is really no different from your recursive function. In Line 16, the function calls *itself* with `pos+1` but this call eventually returns and the function continues in line 17. It's `pos` variable also didn't change, it's still `2`. What you're seeing isn't `pos` magically changing or control jumping from line 18 to line 17, it's literally *returning* back to the previous call of `comb`.

Comment: OK, so comb() is called with pos + 1 at line 18, which means the if statement is true. After the return at line 13, what line does control return to?